# MongoDB Remote Access HostNotFound

Tags: mongodb, remote-access

I am trying to remotely access a MongoDB database that I set up on a Windows machine. I have gone into the `mongod.cfg` file and changed the `bind_Ip` setting to `0.0.0.0` which should allow for any other machine to access the database.

However, I still can't remotely access the database from my laptop. I'm using the host name that I get when I use the command `getHostName()` on the machine where the database is running. When I try to connect I get the error `"connection attempt failed: HostNotFound: Could not find address for ....: SocketException: Host not found (authoritative): "`. What am I doing wrong here? Is it an issue with firewalls and if so how do I change that on a Windows machine?

Comment: Try `ping "hostname" ` from your remote machine to check , if you are able to reach the host or not

Comment: When I run `ping "hostname"` it says unknown host. When i run `ping "host IP"` it doesn't connect. This is issue separate from changing `bind_Ip`?

Comment: When you are pinging with host ip, are you getting the response back?

Comment: All requests time out. If the host machine is connected via Ethernet that my remote machine isn't would that be an issue?

Comment: Both the machines should be connected either via intranet or internet.

Comment: Hi @astrachan, did you solve the problem? I am also facing the same issue now.